# Is it possible to change default value for value types variables?

Tags: c#

I'm just curious to know, is it possible to change default value of e.g. int in C# and I can have a value -1 instead of 0.

```
public class Foo {
    public int i;
}
...
foo = new Foo();
Console.Write(foo.i);
```

so this code must return

```
-1
```

Without explicit initializing

```
public class Foo {
    public int i = -1;
}
```

Can I always be sure, that someone don't print somewhere something like

```
#define TRUE FALSE
```

but for default value of int

P.S. for interest purposes only.

Comment: just declare i as -1.

Comment: You need to initialize it `public int i = -1;`

Comment: As a sidenote, pre C# 6.0 the solutions given won't work for `struct` types, because they can't have parameterless instance initializers (and directly assigning `public int i  = -1` is considered to be one). C# 6.0 should introduce parameterless instance initializers for `struct` types.

Comment: @xanatos the xor solution will work just fine for struct types; of course, structs should be immutable *anyway*, in which case we should expect the desired field value to be a  (perhaps optional) constructor parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, basically. Assuming you don't initialize fields, the memory space is simply zeroed. You shouldn't expose fields directly *anyway*.

One trick I have seen to get around this (used by the capnp serializer, which works against raw memory, not objects) is to use xor. For example: if the default is -1, you can xor the value in and out:

```
public class Foo {
    private int i;
    public int I {
        get { return i ^ -1; }
        set { i = value ^ -1; }
    }
}
```

This has no initialization, and does what you want. For use  with types other than bools and integers this is more complex, but still possible - but it would be easier to use an initializer.

Note that for the `-1` case, you could use "not" rather than "xor":

```
public class Foo {
    private int i;
    public int I {
        get { return ~i; }
        set { i = ~value; }
    }
}
```

However: a field initializer (`int i = -1;`) or a constructor (`public Foo() { i = -1; }`) is probably simpler.

Comment: Thanks for really good answer, main meaning of the question was can I always be sure, that someone don't print somewhere something like
#define TRUE FALSE
but for default value of int, so I can receive unexpected behavior of program? I think the answer, fortunately, is "No".

Answer (score 3):

You can't change *int*'s default value, but you can set *Foo*'s variables default value:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int i;
    public Foo()
    {
        i = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, but question is about changing value of default type, not initialize

Comment: You can't change int's default value. This is an answer.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you can not change the default value of value types.
But you can certainly initialize it to a value you want.

for eg.

```
public class Foo {
    public int i = -1;
}
...
foo = new Foo();
Console.Write(foo.i);
```

it will return

```
-1
```

Comment: Yes, of course, but I'm intresting in changing value of default type, not initialize.

Comment: As mentioned multiple times, there is no way to achieve what you want. If there was a real need for something like that, it would probably exist.

Can you explain why you think such an approach would be good?
All I can see it doing is adding confusion, as you can't look at a piece of code and get a clear picture of how it works unless you go and check if someone somewhere changed the default values.

Imagine someone marking a boolean as true by default. Awful.

Comment: There's a reason types are initialized to a default, that's for consistency and predictability.

Comment: I don't need it, just curious, I'm also think that this is awful, but I wanna to know if someone could do that.

Answer (score 0):

A nice solution would be to override `default(T)`, but you can't override this keyword. It is always null for reference types and zero for value types.